# How to write the SQL query for summarizing salary

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

Q. I want a update query for updating the sum of salaries of employees departmentwise in the dept 
table

```
DEPT table : columns :: DEPTNO  DNAME     LOC      SUM_SAL
                          10    'CC'     'BLR' 
                          20   'ADMIN'   'DEL'
                          30    'HR'      'CAL'
```

```
update a
set sum_sal = b.sum_sal
from dept a,
(select deptno, sum(sal) sum_sal from emp group by deptno ) b
 where a.deptno = b.deptno;
```

But it is not working

```
update a
set sum_sal = b.sum_sal
from dept a,
(select deptno, sum(sal) sum_sal from emp group by deptno ) b
 where a.deptno = b.deptno;

 update a
   set sum_sal = b.sum_sal
   from dept a,
   (select deptno, sum(sal) sum_sal from emp group by deptno ) b
     where a.deptno = b.deptno;
from dept a,
```

> ERROR at line 3: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: the error "not properly ended" is because you have a `,` not a `;`

Comment: And there's no `from` keyword in [`update`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/UPDATE.html). Maybe you wanted [`merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/MERGE.html).

Answer (score 1):

Oracle doesn't support a `from` clause in an `update`.

Just use a correlated subquery:

```
update dept
    set sum_sal = (select sum(e.sal) from emp e where e.deptno = dept.deptno);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using `with..as select ...` clause within an update statement :

```
update dept d
   set d.sum_sal = 
                  ( with e as (
                               select * 
                                 from emp
                              )
                   select sum(e.sal) 
                     from e 
                    where e.deptno = d.deptno
                    group by e.deptno
                  );
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5d478a1225b8e104742f11f3b791b6ac)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MERGE` statement as it is a good candidate for `MERGE`

Try the following query:

```
MERGE INTO DEPT D 
USING 
(
    SELECT
        E.DEPTNO,
        SUM(E.SAL) SUM_SAL
    FROM
        EMP E
    GROUP BY
        E.DEPTNO
) E 
ON ( E.DEPTNO = DEPT.DEPTNO )
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET D.SUM_SAL = E.SUM_SAL;
```

Cheers!!